# Trying to calculate the value of the gamma function using Gauss-Laguerre quadrature without inbuilt functions

Tags: python, integration, gaussian

Im trying to write a program that calculates the value of the gamma function(defined by integral(t^(n-1)*e^(-t)*dt) ) for any value n in python. However, my answers are very wrong and I don't know what I am doing incorrect.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Here's the code for a sample case of gamma(5):

```
import math


# Define the function to be integrated (f(x) = x^4 * e^(-x))
def integrand(x):
    return x**4 * math.exp(-x)

# Gauss-Laguerre quadrature weights and nodes for n=5
weights = [0.2635603197181409102030619, 1.413403059106516792218407, 3.59642577104072208112447, 7.08581000585883755692212, 12.64080084427578265943]
nodes = [0.1834346424956498, 0.9165752759150713, 2.4148302753646825, 4.2898664265427511, 7.209661773352202]

# Calculate the value of the gamma function using Gauss-Laguerre quadrature
gamma_value = 0
for i in range(len(weights)):
    gamma_value += weights[i] * integrand(nodes[i])

# Display the result
print("Gamma(5) calculated using Gauss-Laguerre quadrature:", gamma_value)
```

The answer is supposed to be 24 but it prints 69.47.

Comment: We are not all-knowing math experts here. Where did you get this formula from? There is little coding here, so if you get wrong results, likely your formula is just wrong...

Comment: Simple googling leads to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature where you'll see that `f(x)` should not contain the `exp(-x)` factor... Then you drop your `weights` and `nodes` on us with no justification, so I won't even look at them... [ask]

Comment: That is how the gamma function is defined @Julien Source - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: What you have as “weights” are actually the nodes. It’s appropriate to use this type of quadrature for the gamma function expressed as an integral (though it’s a bit pointless for integer values), but the function that you weight shouldn’t include the exponential function. Note that there is no correspondence between the argument of the gamma function and the number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the weights and nodes used for Gauss-Laguerre quadrature. In your code, they did not match the order `n=5`, resulting in an incorrect calculation.

To compute the gamma function accurately using Gauss-Laguerre quadrature in Python, you can use the SciPy library, which provides functions for numerical integration, including Gauss-Laguerre quadrature.

```py
import scipy.integrate as spi
import numpy as np

# Define the function to be integrated (f(x) = x^(n-1) * e^(-x))
def integrand(x, n):
    return x**(n-1) * np.exp(-x)

# Set the value of n
n = 5

# Use SciPy to compute the gamma function using Gauss-Laguerre quadrature
gamma_value, _ = spi.quad(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=(n,))

# Display the result
print(f"Gamma({n}) calculated using SciPy Gauss-Laguerre quadrature:", gamma_value)
```

Here SciPy handles the computation of the appropriate weights and nodes for `n=5`, ensuring an accurate result. You can replace `n` with any other value to calculate the gamma function for a different order.

Using SciPy for numerical integration tasks like this is recommended as it simplifies the process and provides reliable results.

Answer (score 0):

What you have as "weights" are actually the nodes. I don't know what the other array is supposed to be.

Since the technique is aimed at integrands of type f(x)exp(-x) on interval [0,inf) it is conventional only to supply the f(x) part.

```
# Define the NON-EXPONENTIAL part of the function to be integrated
# i.e. f(x) in full integrand f(x) e^(-x))
def part_integrand(x):
    return x ** 4

weights = [0.52175561058280865248, 0.39866681108317592745, 0.075942449681707595388, 0.0036117586799220484545, 0.000023369972385776227891]
nodes = [0.26356031971814091020, 1.4134030591065167922, 3.5964257710407220812, 7.0858100058588375569, 12.640800844275782659]

# Calculate the integral
integral = 0
for w, x in zip( weights, nodes ):
    integral += w * part_integrand( x )

print( "Integral = ", integral )
```

Output:

```
Integral =  23.999999999999996
```